# How to fix Java heap space error in Talend?

Tags: talend

I have an ETL flow through `talend` and there:

1. Read the zipped files from a remote server with a job.
2. Take this files unzipes them and parse them into HDFS with a job. Inside the job exists a schema check so if something is not

My problem is that TAC server stopes the execution because of this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
> at org.talend.fileprocess.TOSDelimitedReader$ColumnBuffer4Joiner.saveCharInJoiner(TOSDelimitedReader.java:503)
> at org.talend.fileprocess.TOSDelimitedReader.joinAndRead(TOSDelimitedReader.java:261)
> at org.talend.fileprocess.TOSDelimitedReader.readRecord_SplitField(TOSDelimitedReader.java:148)
> at org.talend.fileprocess.TOSDelimitedReader.readRecord(TOSDelimitedReader.java:125)
> ....

Is there any option to avoid and handle this error automatically?
There are only few files which cause this error but I want to find a solution for further similar situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the TAC Job Conductor, for a selected job, you can add JVM parameters.

[image]

Add  the **-Xmx** parameter to specify the maximum heap size. The default value depends on various factors like the JVM release/vendor, the actual memory of the machine, etc... In your situation, the `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` reveals that the default value is not enough for this job so you need to override it.

For example, specify  `-Xmx2048m`  for 2048Mb or 2gb

Comment: Thanks a lot. Is it possible to explain further please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

@DrGenius Talend has java based environment and some default jvm heap is awarded during initialization, as in for any java program.  Default for Talend - Min:256MB (xms) & max:1024MB.. As per your job requirement,  you can set the range of min/max jvm like min of 512 mb & max 8gb..

This can be modified from Job run tab - advance setting.. Even this can be parameterized and can be overwritten using variables set in env.  Exact value can be seen from job build -> _run.sh ..
But be careful not to set high as too high so that other jobs running on same server is depleted of memory.

More details on heap error & how to debug issue:
https://dzone.com/articles/java-out-of-memory-heap-analysis